# Stl way to fill vector instead /out.clear();out.reserve(n);loop{out.p_b(el.foo)}/

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, std

Is there a func in `std` to fill `out` with the same meaning?

```
template <class T> struct S {
  template <class U> void f(std::vector<U> &out) {
    out.clear();
    out.reserve(v_.size());
    for (const auto &el : v_) {
      out.push_back(el.foo);
    }
  }
  std::vector<T> v_;
};
```

Comment: Dare I ask what `v_` is ? Regardless, You have a basic `transform` by the looks of it, assuming you want the same result and there is a 1-to-1 relationship between the content of `out` and the `foo` member content from `v_` (whatever it is).

Comment: [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)?

Comment: @WhozCraig `v_` is a vector, and I want to `out` has a specific field of `v_` elements. May you suggest `transform` way in comment, pls?

Comment: @justANewbie I don't see `std::fill` can help me without `out.resize()` to use `end()` iterator which leads to overhead ctor calls. Please, post the example.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Please explain what's wrong with this question? Compilable and self-explainable snippet. The question is to get library tool to do snippet behavior.

Comment: What is the exact purpose of this structure? I believe you will not find a STL structure which is specific to `foo` content in a type `U`. Maybe if you add more detail about the exact functionallity you want, it may be reopen.

Comment: @AdrianMaire There was no structure until the question was closed with 'not reproducible' reason or smth like that (I've added `v_` in struct to show where from 'out' gets values). The main part is `out.clear(); out.reserve(); out.push_back(...);` here. I want to know if there is a func. (with an example of usage, please) which does the snippet actions with no worse efficiency.

Comment: I believe the combination of clear(), reserve (which is specific to some few containers), and fill with uncompatible type is quite specific, I don't know of any equivalent all-in-one STL function.
You can look at `copy` or ` for_each` which can help making this code "for-loop-free".